# Use desktop as hotspot

Tags: windows-7, linux, internet, lan

I have a windows 7 desktop that is connected to the internet through wi-fi. I have a linux laptop that I want to share the internet with through a LAN able form my desktop to my laptop? HOw do I set my desktop up to be the internet for my laptop?

Update: I do not see am option for how to share this

[image]

Comment: Has it to be via lan?

Comment: yes, i need to install wireless drivers for my laptop.

Comment: use connectify. www.connectify.me

Comment: I installed that program and I need the 'PRO' version to use it in my case. I uninstalled it, it removed my wireless drivers all together. I had to spend an hours fixing that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great tutorial, how you can do it without any additional tools.

> 1. Click the Windows icon and type "view network connections", then hit "Enter" on your keyboard.  [image]
> 2. Right-click on the icon that represents your wireless connection to the internet, then left-click on "Properties"
>      [image]
> 3. Go to the "Sharing" tab and check the top box, then choose "Local Area Connection" from the drop down below. No need to check the second
>      box. Just press "OK" at the bottom of the screen.
>      [image]
> 4. When everything is ready to go you will see the word "Shared" under your wireless connection to the Internet. Its sharing with your
>      computers ethernet port (also called "Local Area Connection" on this
>      screen).
>      [image]
>
> Now you can connect an
>   ethernet cable to your computers ethernet port and share internet to a
>   second device.
>
> **Note**: To return normal ethernet port functionality to your computer, just repeat the above and uncheck the top box, then press
>   "OK

[Tutorial](http://www.countrymilewifi.com/how-to-share-computers-wifi-with-ethernet-devices.aspx)